# Will unnamed constraints be generated with different placeholder names each time a script is run on a different server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got a database that has unnamed, or what appear to be randomly generated names for some of it's constraints.

Names like: `DF___MyTable_Busin_CompE_139BEED8`

When we have a new version of the application to provide to the client that involves DB changes we provide scripts generated by Visual Studio's DB project functionality to the client.

This time we're getting reports of errors like `Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.`

When I check the script we provided it does drop the constraint before adding the new default.

So I'm wondering if these constraints are being generated with different names on different servers and then when the script goes to drop the existing default constraint it attempts to drop a constraint that doesn't exist and then fails again when attempting to add a new default constraint to the field?

I'm more of a C# guy, less of a SQL guy, not sure how these things work.

Comment: If you don't define the name of a `CONSTRAINT` then SQL Server will call it what ever it want (it does follow some rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your thinking is correct. You cannot rely on the generated names of constraints.

There is no guarantee that a constraint name will be generated the same on two systems or even on the same system if you were to drop and re-create a constraint. You should always try to use named constraints.